# Can we implement a REST service using Akka and Camel Integration?

Tags: scala, rest, apache-camel, akka

I was reading about Akka and Camel integration. I cam across Camel for the first time and it sounds wonderful. Can we build a REST service using Akka and Camel plainly? Any useful pointers in that direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For building REST services with Camel use one of these Camel components

- [camel-cxfrs](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html)
- [camel-restlet](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html)

You can use both components within Akka (via the akka-camel integration module).